# i18n with wp_kses() with printf() for multiple parameter

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, printf

I've a string like the following:

```
<?php
/** pre_wp_version() is to return version dynamically */
printf( __('<strong>Plugin Name</strong> requires WordPress core version <strong>%1$s</strong> or greater. The plugin has been <strong>deactivated</strong>. Consider <a href="%2$s">upgrading WordPress</a>.', 'plugin-text-domain' ), pre_wp_version(), admin_url('/update-core.php') );
```

I came to know that, it's buggy, and risky too. So I want to use `wp_kses()` with this as [stated in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#HTML).

The codex has an example on how to implement it:

```
<p>
<?php
$url = 'http://example.com';
$link = sprintf( wp_kses( __( 'Check out this link to my <a href="%s">website</a> made with WordPress.', 'my-text-domain' ), array(  'a' => array( 'href' => array() ) ) ), esc_url( $url ) );
echo $link;
?>
</p>
```

But the example is showing only a single parameter, but in my case I've multiple parameters for `printf()`. How can I use `wp_kses()` with the present scenario with i18n function?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved it as follows:

```
printf( wp_kses( __('<strong>Plugin Name</strong> requires WordPress core version <strong>%1$s</strong> or greater. The plugin has been <strong>deactivated</strong>. Consider <a href="%2$s">upgrading WordPress</a>.', 'plugin-text-domain' ), array( 'a' => array('href' => array()), 'strong' => array() ) ), pre_wp_version(), admin_url('/update-core.php') );
```

Though, in production I've reduced the `<strong>` tags for easy translation.

Any descent solution would be much appreciated.